# Replace for loop with a stream

Tags: java

I am more famiiliar with c# and  linq but I have to work on some java code, so for the sake of learning and refactoring I was wondering if I can replace a for loop that Im using twice with a stream. I have a collection with a class object and then looping thru that collection and calling a function in that class. A few lines later I am doing the same thing just callinga  different function. Looking at it and with my very new and limited knoweledge of java streams I was wondering if I can refactor a bit a la linq and pull the class object and just call the function

```
  Collection<RowProcessingHandler> rowHandlers = getRowHandlers();
    for (RowProcessingHandler handler : rowHandlers) {
        handler.onProcessingStarting(columnMap);
        handler.onProcess(dataList);
    }
```

Can I use a stream to get RowProcessingHandler handler and then I can just call onProcessingStarting(columnMap); and handler.onProcess(dataList); from a variable as so

```
 RowProcessingHandler handler = rowHandlers.stream().findFirst();
```

Which throws an error of Incompatible types

Comment: The error is correct. `findFirst()` returns an optional type. So your handler variable's type should be `Optional< RowProcessingHandler>`. Please have a look at Javadoc. It will give you information on what the method's signature is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing fine, but the error originates from the fact that the stream API provides an `Optional<T>` as result from `findFirst()` because the stream potentially could be empty.

```
Optional<RowProcessingHandler> handlerOpt = rowHandlers.stream().findFirst();
if (handlerOpt.isPresent()) {
  RowProcessingHandler handler = handlerOpt.get()
}
```

or if you are sure that there is an entry in the stream you could do:

```
RowProcessingHandler handler = rowHandlers.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow();
```

depending on what you are about to do, this API might be more fluent:

```
rowHandlers.stream().forEach(handler => {
  handler.onProcessingStarting(columnMap);
  handler.onProcess(dataList);
});
```

Note that the scope of variables is a bit different in comparison to for-loops. If you use a variable within a stream scope (here for example `columnMap`) it must be [effectively final](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables).